# Computing the maximum antichain when incomparability relations are given as LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, graph, combinatorics, poset

I am trying to compute the [maximum antichain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain) for a given [poset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). 
I have created the following method:

```
public boolean isIncomparable(Node a,Node b)
{
    if(isReachable(a,b)||isReachable(b,a))
         return false;
    return true;
}
```

which returns true if and only if the two nodes are incomparable (i.e.,there is no path from `a` to `b`  nor from `b` to `a` ).

I defined a LinkedHashMap

```
LinkedHashMap<Node,ArrayList<Node>> map=new LinkedHashMap<Node,ArrayList<Node>>();
```

which maps every node N to its incomparable elements `Incomp(N)`.

```
for(int i=0;i<nodes.size();i++)
{
   Node a=nodes.get(i);
   ArrayList<Node> tmp=new ArrayList<Node>();
   for(int j=i+1;j<nodes.size();j++)
   {
      Node b=nodes.get(j);
      if(isIncomparable(a,b))
           tmp.add(b)
   }
   map.put(a,tmp);
}
```

For example: assume the elements are {A,B,C,D} with the following relation A>B, A>C, D>C then

```
Incomp(A)={D}
Incomp(B)={C,D}
Incomp(C)={}
Incomp(D)={}
```

Notice that duplicates are not allowed (i.e. `Incomp(C)={B}` but since (B,C) is in `Incomp(B)` we do not need to repeat it).

I am stuck here. Should I just check incomparability among `Incomp(N)` elements and then get the key with maximum size as the maximum antichain? In other words, how to find the maximum antichain with this setting?

I can't go with generating all subsets of size k as this going to be inefficient.

Comment: You seem to think that there is a unique maximum antichain which is wrong in a general poset.

Comment: @hivert thank you. Yes I know; I am actually looking only for its size (i.e. width)